# Can a button be used to run cpu intensive code and then display the results using c# and asp.net for a web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, cpu-usage

I am currently trying to create an application which has a homepage. On this homepage there is a button which is going to run CPU intensive code and then display the results. As I stated in the title the application is using ASP.NET and C# not Windows Forms which some other websites I have looked at seem to suggest.

I am relatively new to C# and have not attempted this in any other programming language. I also have no code to show as I don't really know how to progress this.

Comment: Are you planning to run this on a server? Do you want the processing to occur on the server? Or in the browser?

Comment: Start out just doing your CPU intensive code right in the click handler of the button.  If you have any problems with that solution (most likely would be performance related, not functional), then go from there.  About the only change that an end user would see would be that you might want it to be asynchronous.  Just throw that section into an UpdatePanel so they can interact with the rest of the page while it's happening.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I am going to be hosting the app online in the cloud. I would like the processing to occur in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It can run CPU intensive code on the server, yes. Note that this will typically block your web application from sending a response in a reasonable amount of time and the web application could appear to be frozen.

What type of CPU intensive code did you have in mind? There are many ways to handle this scenario.

Comment: I was thinking of making it cycle through a loop a good amount of times and increasing the amount to see if there is any change in the amount of cpu being used. Do you think this is a good idea or should i try something else?

Answer (score 0):

By "CPU intensive" I assume you mean it will take a long time for the process to complete?  In a web application anything that takes more than a few moments should be done asynchronously.  In the request/response model of HTTP it's best (for a number of reasons) to respond quickly to a client making a request.

In the case of a long-running process, by "asynchronous" I do not mean using AJAX, as that's still a request/response like any other.

By "asynchronous" what I mean in this case is that you want to have a separate server-side process which handles the CPU intensive task, and the web application does nothing more than queue the task for running and check the status of the task when people look for it.  Then it can report the results of the task after it's done.

So a basic overview of the architecture would be something like this:

1. A user in the web application clicks a button to "start the task."
2. The web application inserts a record into a database table indicating that the task has been queued (maybe with a user ID of who queued it, a time stamp, anything else you'll need to know).
3. A separate scheduled application (console application or Windows Service, most likely) is perpetually running. (Either using a timer in an always-running Windows Service or scheduled to run over and over, such as every few minutes, as a console application.)  This application checks the database table for new queued tasks.
4. When the application sees a task, it marks it as "started" in the database (so subsequent runs of the application don't try to run the same task in parallel) and starts running it.
5. The web application can see the status of the task in the database table and display it to users who request it, so users can see that it's still running.
6. When the task is completed, the task record in the database table is updated and the result is stored somewhere.  (Depending on what the result is.  Data?  In the database.  A report file of some sort?  Save as a file somewhere.  That's all up to you.)
7. The web application can see the status of the task as completed and any other information recorded, and users can request to view the output of the task.

The main thing to remember here is to break up the responsibilities into **two applications**.  The web application is for the purpose of providing a user interface.  A web application is not suited for long-running background tasks.  So that responsibility is moved to a separate application which is better suited for that purpose.  The two applications coordinate via a shared database.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your answer. Would I still need two applications if I was the only one using the web application? My main objective was to have the same program; one hosted online the other locally and compare the two to see if there was any difference in performance.

Comment: @AlexT: Well, I suppose if the browser doesn't time out, then you can just run the task in-line in the web application.  If there are no users to concern yourself with and this is just a purely academic exercise then you should be fine.

Comment: ok that is good to hear. However as I have never done this before, I have no idea how to make my program more cpu intensive or how to display the results without using a messagebox. Could you shed some light on this?

Comment: @AlexT: Ah, that sounds like a very different question than how this one has been interpreted.  What you're asking now is what code can you write to run a benchmark test on your machine.  A Google search for "C# CPU benchmark" has a couple of promising results, including a code project that you should be able to use.  It's a Windows Forms project, but you should be able to extract the code needed into your own project.  At this point you're going to want to be a lot more specific about what you're trying to measure, though.  As well as why, because there could be a better way to do it.

Comment: Ok on my home page i have a button, at the minute when you press the button it does loops and reports back how many ms it took to complete. What i would like is to measure how much cpu is being used while the loops are being completed.